# Windows-8 & Internet Explorer-10 broke my ActiveX control drawing?

Tags: windows-8, activex, windbg, internet-explorer-10

I am experiencing a very weird behavior while running my Active-X control on “Windows 8” OS, and browser “Microsoft Internet-Explorer 10”.

The control:
My Active-X control is very stable product that my company is already distributing for several years between hundreds of happy customers.   The control is an ATL custom-draw control, written in C++, and built with “Visual Studio 2008”.

The problem – the drawing disappears:
While I press the link that opens my control for the first time, I can see that my control is being painted gradually (as my data loading is sometimes slow), but eventually all the drawing disappears, leaving a blank white background color where the controls is located.

Using ‘Spy++’ I can see that my control is really there, but all its painting disappear.
If I move the browser or change its size the control will be re-painted, but otherwise it is simply not visible.

I tried to debug this problem and find out who is erasing my drawing.
I came up with the following technique:

1. Using WinDBG I added breakpoints at ‘user32.dll’ DLL on the following methods: user32!InvalidateRect, user32!InvalidateRgn, user32!FillRect,
2. I defined these methods to only show stack and continue with to run,
3. I ran the above problematic scenario,
4. When the problem happens I am trying to view who called ‘Invalidate’ or ‘FillRect’,
5. Since all this happens very quickly I am using the ‘Print Screen’ button to freeze the moment

After doing this several times I find that exactly at the time my control disappears the following stack calls ‘user32!FillRect’:

```
user32!FillRect
MSHTML!memcpy+0x9805
MSHTML!COmWindowProxy::SwitchMarkup+0x468
MSHTML!CMarkup::SetInteractiveInternal+0x428
MSHTML!CMarkup::RequestReadystateInteractive+0x98
MSHTML!CMarkup::BlockScriptExecutionHelper+0xde
MSHTML!CHtmPost::Exec+0x794
MSHTML!CHtmPost::Run+0x1c
MSHTML!PostManExecute+0x5f
MSHTML!PostManResume+0x7b
MSHTML!CHtmPost::OnDwnChanCallback+0x3a
MSHTML!CDwnChan::OnMethodCall+0x19
MSHTML!GlobalWndOnMethodCall+0x169
MSHTML!GlobalWndProc+0xd7
user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x100
user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x3ef
user32!DispatchMessageW+0x10
IEFRAME!CTabWindow::_TabWindowThreadProc+0x981
IEFRAME!LCIETab_ThreadProc+0x378
iertutil!CIsoWinMsg::PostQueuedMessagesToComponent+0x4b
IEShims!NS_CreateThread::DesktopIE_ThreadProc+0x66
KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x72
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

This is consistent.
When examining this stack I found that this message belongs to a window of class `Internet Explorer_Hidden`, which is window of size `zero (0x0)`, but with a `WS_VISIBLE` style. This window belongs to the browser.

Does anyone know this phenomenon?
Is it possible that the browser hidden window is causing this problem?
Could you recommend on other approach to try and hunt the stack that is erasing my drawing?

Many thanks for any hint!

Paz Offer

Comment: It is a common sign of leaking GDI handles, a bug that can go undetected for a long time.

Comment: I am not sure if leaking GDI handles is related to this problem because (a) the problem happens when I start the browser and open my AXCtrl for the very first time, and (b) the total number of GDI objects at this stage is around 70 for the whole IE process, which does not sound much (unless I am missing something).

Comment: Well, take this as a sign that we have no good way to debug the code for you.  Use Microsoft Support if you can't debug this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion:
**The bug was in `Microsoft Internet Explorer 10`**

I used Microsoft Support service to farther investigate this problem. Enclosed here are the findings:

Microsoft Support viewed the version of my IE (`Internet Explorer`) and suggested to first upgrade IE to its latest patch.

As it happens, the machine I was working on was not setup to be automatically updated by the `Windows Update` service for some time. As part of upgrading IE I had to first update windows using `Windows Update` service to its latest patches.

During the process of `Windows Update` the `Microsoft Internet Explorer 10` was automatically  updated to its latest patch.
Once IE updated the problem disappeared.
In addition, the ActiveX GUI load process became much faster.

The old version of `Microsoft Internet Explorer 10`, which caused the problem:

- Version: 10.0.9200.16384
- Update Versions: RTM (KB2718695)

The new version of `Microsoft Internet Explorer 10`, which solved the problem:

- Version: 10.0.9200.16635
- Update Versions: 10.0.7 (KB2846071)

Now all is working as expected.

Thanks, Pazo